# is there any shortcut to zoom in and out in SceneBuilder

Tags: scenebuilder

i'm using scene builder version 15, and I'm wondering if there is any available shortcut to zoom in and out easily instead of going to menu->view->zoom.

Ps:
-i tried Ctrl + "++" but it doesn't work
-i'm using windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zooming in and out works for me. I am using Windows and Scene Builder 16.0.0.

Instead of pressing '+' on numeric keyboard i press '+' that is an alternative sign on '=' key. (Two keys right from '0').

For zooming out i use '/' key also not on numeric keyboard, but a key that is one key left from right 'shift' or three keys right from 'm'.

Note that distances might slightly vary from keyboard to keyboard.

Attaching picture for better visualization:
[image: Keyboard visualization]